# How to fix "unrecognized guid format"?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, guid

i'm getting "unrecognized guid format" error in my asp.net MVC application when i try to select Guid from mysql database.

```
        var contact_cstm = ctx.contacts_cstm.Where(x => x.national_id_c == model.NID).FirstOrDefault();
        
        if (contact_cstm != null)
        {                        
            var contact = ctx.contacts.Where(x => x.id  == contact_cstm.id_c && x.deleted==false).FirstOrDefault();
            
            if (contact != null)
            {
                model.FName = contact.first_name;
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
```

in contact_cstm  I am getting the GUID fine,

but in the second query when I use where clause it will show me the error.

```
var contact = ctx.contacts.Where(x => x.id  == contact_cstm.id_c && x.deleted==false).FirstOrDefault();
```

My ContactModel

```
public partial class contact
{
    public System.Guid id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string phone_mobile { get; set; }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.]
   System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result) +12635324
   System.Guid..ctor(String g) +108
   MySql.Data.Types.MySqlGuid.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.ReadValue(MySqlPacket packet, Int64 length, Boolean nullVal) +205
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject) +168
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.ReadColumnData(Boolean outputParms) +65
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior) +158
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read() +62
   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.Read() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +36

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.HandleReaderException(Exception e) +4816212
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +49
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +41
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +114
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +168
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +42
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +119
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +106
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +220
   RegaSelfService.BLL.ContactBLL.updateUserIfExist(ContactModel model) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Rega_selfService\RegaSelfService\RegaSelfService\BLL\ContactBLL.cs:46
   RegaSelfService.Controllers.<login>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Rega_selfService\RegaSelfService\RegaSelfService\Controllers\ContactController.cs:42
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
```

Comment: The problem is that you're doing `contact_cstm.otp_c = num.ToString();` which results in GUIDs that are not [correctly formatted](http://guid.one/guid), as a GUIDs format must be `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` where `x` is any alphanumerical character, `M` is the version and `N` the variant

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, contact_cstm.otp_c is not relevant to the question so I removed it. This is just to update the OTP it does not have anything to do with the GUID.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio is the tool you use to author your code, it doesn't play a role in actually executing your code. You can also author your code in Visual Studio Code, MonoDevelop, JetBrains' Rider, etc. and you would still get the same error when you run it!

Comment: Please add stacktrace as text, not image.

Comment: i added stack trace as text now :)

Comment: Can you check the contents of your table, in all "guid" columns? My guess is that you have something in there that isn't a guid. I say this because the stack trace indicates it was trying to read a column value.

Comment: yes all columns are "guid" Type

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :

```
var id_c = new Guid(contact_cstm.id_c);

var contact = ctx.contacts.Where(x => x.id  == id_c && x.deleted==false).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: So, why is the OP trying this? A good answer will explain the problem, and the solution